# Get name after word with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

i'm trying to get the first word after a determined word, that's how i'm doing:

Text:

```
Companie: 'Stack over flow';
```

Regex:

```
var reg = new RegExp('Companie' + '.*?(\\w\\S*)', 'i');
var match   = reg.exec(text);
```

The output will be:

```
'Stack'.
```

I want receive all the name, but this name is dinamically, sometimes there are just one word, sometime 5, sometime 2.. etc

Possible?

Thanks.

Comment: There are many holes in your description. Unfortunately, without good examples, the answers might not be of help to what is in your mind.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say that isn't a scenario where a regex should be used, but something like this instead:

```js
var str = 'Companie: Stack over flow';
var name = str.split('Companie:')[1].trim();
alert(name);
```

Comment: This produces `"Stack over flow"` instead of `"Stack"`

Comment: @Oriol That's what OP wants

Comment: The question says "first word", which I guess is only `"Stack"`. But you might be right because the question is not much clear.

Answer (score 2):

michael has a good answer, but if you want a regex for that, you can go with

```
var text = "Companie: 'Stack over flow';"
var reg = /^Companie: '(.*)';$/
var match = reg.exec(text)[1];
```

The value of `match` is

```
"Stack over flow"
```